# Is it possible to disable split screen view from metro app (windows 8)?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a metro app that will behave funny when user uses the "split screen" windows 8 functionality (as in the following image: http://pureinfotech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/metro-app-desktop-split-screen-windows-8.png).

Is there a way to programatically disable from inside of your app? I haven't found any so far, but I am posting this just in case anyone knows any better.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot.

I would recommend just navigating to a Splash Screen sort of thing.

Look what happens when you snap the Windows Store.

Comment: I see, so, there would be two cases to consider:

   1) When another app is active (let's call it app B), and I introduce my app as a secondary split view. For this case I can use a splash screen, the same way windows store does. Do you know how they achieve this? How can they identify if it is entering as a split window?

    2) When the active app is my application and I try to enter app B as a split window. Can I also identify this happened?

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible but probably it won't pass the app certification.

You can try using ApplicationView.TryUnsnap() 
in the event handler for SizeChanged event of your Page:

In ctor put:

```
Window.Current.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
```

And implement the handler method:

```
public void OnSizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.Value)
        {
            case Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState.Filled:
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Fill", false);
                break;
            case Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState.FullScreenLandscape:
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Full", false);
                break;
            case Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState.Snapped:
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Snapped", false);
                break;
            case Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState.FullScreenPortrait:
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Portrait", false);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        this.ShowCurrentViewState();
    }


void ShowCurrentViewState()
    {
        ApplicationViewState currentState = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.Value;
        if (currentState == ApplicationViewState.Snapped)
        {
            ApplicationView.TryUnsnap() ;
        }

   }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, haven't had a change to take into this, but I promise I will test and comment, thanks!